# Is there a notation that allows me to refer to the first/second element of an ordered pair?

Tags: notation

In programming, we define an "array" (basically an ordered n-tuple) in the following way:

$$a=[3,5].$$

Later on, if we want to refer to the first element of the predetermined array/pair/n-tuple, we write $a[0]$ (because in programming you start counting from $0$, not $1$), which will be equal to $3$.

Is there a similar notation for doing this in mathematics? E.g something like `(3,5).firstElement`, which would equal $3$? Or is such a reference only possible by using the set-theoretic definition of an ordered pair?

Comment: Maybe [first- second-projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_pair#Kuratowski's_definition): $\pi_1((a,b))$ and similar.

Comment: I know of no general answer to your question. The set theoretic implementation (which is just that, not the definition) is not good in your use case. If you [edit] the question to tell us why you need this notation we may be able to help you define one appropriate for your problem.

Answer (score 6):

A standard notation (used in Dieudonné, Foundations of Modern Analysis, page 12; Bourbaki, General Topology, Chapter 1, §4.1, page 44.) is $\operatorname{pr_i}(a_1,\cdots,a_n)=a_i$ since, given a set $A$, the map $$A^n\to A:(a_1,\cdots,a_n) \mapsto a_i$$ is called the $i$-th projection.

This notation has the merit that we have (almost) the same word in French (*projection*), German (*Projektion*), Dutch (*projectie*), Italian (*proiezione*), Spanish (*proyección*), etc...and all these words also start with  "pr".

Answer (score 3):

If $X$ and $Y$ are sets, the function $f:X\times Y\to X$ given by $f(x,y)=x$ is called the *projection from $X\times Y$ onto $X$*; similarly, the function $g:X\times Y\to Y$ given by $g(x,y)=y$ is called the *projection from $X\times Y$ onto $Y$*. A variety of notations for projections are used, but, at least in the case $X=Y=\mathbb R$, it seems common to write $\pi^1$ for $f$ and $\pi^2$ for $g$ (see for instance Spivak's *Calculus on Manifolds*). Using this notation, we can write $\pi^1(3,5)=3$ and $\pi^2(3,5)=5$.

More generally, if $n$ is a positive integer, then the function $\pi^i:\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R$ given by $\pi^i(x_1,\dots,x_n)=x_i$ is called the *$i$th projection function*. Although this is technically a different function for each value of $n$, in practice we gloss over this point.

Answer (score 2):

It's common to assume that the elements of a tuple or vector named $a$ are indexed $a = \langle a_1, a_2, \dots \rangle$, so you would just refer to $a_1$ for the first element.

Similarly, the elements of a matrix $A$ are often assumed to be indexed as $a_{i,j}$.